Wikidata SPARQL: Get Property Value
I used the query builder to find all instances where property Q1902is available. A portion of the query returned by the builder is:
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?statement0 WHERE {
  ?item p:P1902 ?statement0.
  ?statement0 (ps:P1902) _:anyValueP1902.
}
LIMIT 100

How can I get the actual value (or label) of the property returned in the query rather than the link to it?

I don't get why you use a blank node as object in the second triple pattern, maybe the query builder did this? If you want the value of that, you should use a available and select that variable in the projection part of the query: SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?val WHERE {   ?item p:P1902 ?stmt.   ?stmt ps:P1902 ?val } LIMIT 100

You need a variable (instead of a blank node) in place of the value. Currently, you are only querying if a value exists. With a variable, you can get the value in the results.
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?statement0 ?value
WHERE {
  ?item p:P1902 ?statement0 .
  ?statement0 ps:P1902 ?value .
}
LIMIT 100

If you are not interested in the ?statement0 instances, you can use a sequence path:
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?value
WHERE {
  ?item p:P1902/ps:P1902 ?value .
}
LIMIT 100

